# ORMExecuteQuery() count seems to return an array

Tags: orm, coldfusion

ORMExecuteQuery() seem to return an array for the following

```
example = ormExecuteQuery("select count(commentID) as n from pComment c");

output uing cfdump for example would be...
array
[1][x]
```

where x is count.

How can I just get n as a number and not an array object returned? I want to just getn()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
example = ormExecuteQuery("select count(commentID) as n from pComment c", true);
```

Second argument is known as `unique`, despite it's confusing name it makes exactly what you need: makes function to return single value.

Comment: The ColdFusion docs can be horrendous. Here's a source that explicitly says this: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSf0ed2a6d7fb07688310730d81223d0356fc-7ffe.html  Good find, @Sergii.